# Creating portable HTML reports with datagrid features

Tags: javascript, html, datagrid, reporting

When creating business reports, exporting is often an important feature so users can share the data; however you usually have to choose between preserving format (PDF) or preserving data manipulation capabilities (CSV, XLS).

I was thinking of a better exported report format with the following features:

1. One single HTML file that can be used by all major browsers, including mobile versions. Typical use case is some users have access to a complicated system, and others need some of its data, but accessing the system is overkill. Manually exporting and manipulating Excel files is limited and time-consuming.
2. Ability to sort, group/subtotal, and filter the data within the report (so, no server). The generating page/application could filter server data first, then just export what's visible, including grouping/sort, to this file.
3. Ability to print and export to CSV (maybe [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730487/html-client-side-portable-file-generation-no-external-resources-or-server-call)). This should be "just as good" as getting a formatted XLS file, plus increased portability, and it should be trivial to open in a spreadsheet software if needed for additional manipulation.

The general approach to this is not particularly hard to imagine: an HTML datagrid, all source JS files embedded in the file, some export functions for the data. File size is not a huge problem as this would be emailed around, but complicated setups beyond a grid (like charts) are not really in scope.

Has anyone else done this already? Or maybe you can recommend a suitable datagrid project to fork to get things started? I was looking at http://backgridjs.com/ but not sure if it's an amenable candidate.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developper of a little french service called [Appizy](http://appizy.com). As an engineer I often faced the problem of sharing spreadsheets out of my company. I finally ended developping a piece of code to tranform a spreadsheet into a standalone tools in HTML/CSS/JS.

Now I "develop" my tools using a spreadsheet software (OpenOffice or LibreOffice) and share its thanks to Appizy. Let me know if it answers to your needs.

I'm really looking forward some feedback on the service.

BR, Nicolas

Comment: That's pretty neat! I tried a simple invoice and it worked (I'm on vacation so I don't have access to all my stuff). It doesn't quite solve my problem since I don't have and ODS file to start with, and don't need to support "actual" spreadsheets with editing, formulas, etc. but the delivery method is what I was thinking.

If I don't get to implement this and it comes up again with a customer, I'll let them know about your site since they may want to perform that post-processing step themselves, although they may not be able to send data to a third-party hosted service for legal reasons.